# How to define an request body that contains a complex object properties that are not strings in Swagger UI?

Tags: node.js, json, object, swagger-ui, openapi

I am trying to create a swagger endpoint that sends a post request to my API.

Here is what the post request format should look like the following object:

```
{
  payerName: { name: 'test user' },
  payerEmail: { email: 'test@gmail.com' },
  payerFax: { fax: '444-444-4444' },
  payerCity: { city: 'Seattle' },
  payerState: { state: 'WA' }
}
```

I have tried using the following code to do this using swaggerui:

```
/**
 *  @swagger
 *  /api/payers/newPayer:
 *  post:
 *    requestBody:
 *      required: true
 *      content:
 *        application/json:
 *          schema:
 *            type: object
 *            properties:
 *              payerName:
 *                type: object
 *                properties:
 *                  name: 
 *                    type: string
 *              payerEmail:
 *                properties:
 *                  email: 
 *                    type: string
 *              payerFax:
 *                properties:
 *                  fax: 
 *                    type: string
 *              payerCity:
 *                properties:
 *                  city: 
 *                    type: string
 *              payerState:
 *                properties:
 *                  state: 
 *                    type: string
 *            required:
 *              - payerName
 *              - payerEmail
 *            example: {type: "foo","color":"bar"}

 *             
 *    summary: Create a new user
 *    responses:
 *      201:
 *        description: User succesfully created
 *      409:
 *        description: User already exists
 */
```

Unfortunately the output comes out with the properties all as strings.

```
{
  "payerName": {
    "name": "string"
  },
  "payerEmail": {
    "email": "string"
  },
  "payerFax": {
    "fax": "string"
  },
  "payerCity": {
    "city": "string"
  },
  "payerState": {
    "state": "string"
  }
}
```

How can I get the object that I am looking for in the requestbody? Any help would be greatly appreciated ty.

Comment: `"string"` is just an auto-generated sample value for those properties. Consumers can put their own values when they test the requests. Or do you mean you want to display `{"payerName": {"name": "test user"}, "payerEmail": {"email": "test@gmail.com"}, ...}` as the _default example_ in Swagger UI?